# How to align shapes together? (Geometrical Best-Fit Algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, 3d, 2d

I'm working with mecanical engineers who rely on 3D modeling software. These softwares have a "Best Fit" feature. It allows you to acquire data with a sensor (like a 3D scanner) and align the mesured data with a CAD Drawing.

I'd like to know how such an algorithm can work!

In simpler words, imagine that you have 2 NEARLY identical triangles inside a 2D space. One is a 60-60-60 degrees triangle and the other is 60-59-61. The best-fit algorithm would find the best transformation that would align one triangle over the other.

I'm not even sure what I'm searching for here. I've done some research on Best-Fit algorithms but it mostly refer to bin packing and I'm not sure how this relates to my problem. Any advice would be welcome

Comment: An equilateral triangle has no orientation ... so your mapping is not unique

Comment: Finding the optimal superposition of two triangles (or any polygons/polyhedra where you have one-to-one point correspondence) is a well-defined problem and can be solved by the Kabsch algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm.  The larger problem you describe of fitting a CAD drawing with your 3d samples is much harder in general.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it can be done contructing [TRS invariants](http://library.utia.cas.cz/separaty/historie/flusser-rotation%20moment%20invariants%20for%20recognition%20of%20symmetric%20objects.pdf) (TRS: Translation/ Rotation / Scaling).

From the paper:

"Abstract—In this paper, a new set of moment invariants with respect to rotation, translation, and scaling suitable for recognition of objects having N-fold rotation symmetry are presented. Moment invariants described earlier cannot be used for this purpose because most moments of symmetric objects vanish. The invariants proposed here are based on complex moments. Their independence and completeness are proven theoretically and their performance is demonstrated by experiments."

Comment: No, this is taking 2-d images and processing them to solve the object registration problem.  Scale-Invariant Feature Transform (SIFT) is a good example of a similar approach.  The poster has a 3-d point cloud, not 2-d images, so this isn't exactly applicable.

Comment: If the OP is working with 2-d data, I think SIFT is the way to go.  If he has data from a 3-d scanner, then it is isn't a sensical approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Procrustes method on 3-dimensional Kendall shape spaces.

Comment: Hello @coproduct and welcome to StackOverflow. Although your answer does point the reader in the right direction, it would be more helpful if you could provide an explanation of the algorithm you mentioned.