# Best-fit algorithm to fit a set of lines onto a polygon

Tags: algorithm, polygon, shapes

I have two sets of lines, set A and B. The start and end points of all the lines in these two sets are known and I want to find the rotation and translation that best fits set B onto set A. There is no scaling:

[image]

- There is not a one-to-one mapping. I believe this rules out the Kabsch algorithm, though I can envisage a brute force algorithm that uses this.
- Set B is likely to contain partial segments of lines in A. It is likely to contain a pretty sparse number of lines.
- The lines in B will be erroneous - there may be lines observed that do not exist in A.
- There may, of course, be more than one possible 'matches'

For some background, this is part of a crude image-based robot positioning system.

- Set A is a 'map' - data is imported from an imported dxf file.
- Set B is a set one observed lines.

I've had a look around, for example here:

[How to align shapes together? (Geometrical Best-Fit Algorithm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841727/how-to-align-shapes-together-geometrical-best-fit-algorithm)

Is a clever way of doing this? Flicking through image-processing literature shape-matching seems to be more pattern matching for raster images - overkill perhaps for this problem.

The best way I can perceive at the moment is to use a Hough Transform-like approach taking each line in B along each line in A and having bins for the rotation/transformations these represent. I have not coded this and tried it out yet - kind of wanted to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Any ideas and input much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A general solution is to extract "features" from the set A and comparing the features with set B.

One example: Consider all the unique angles in the set A and calculate the different unique pairs of angles. In your example for set A there are only three possible cases: (0,0), (0,90), (90,0). Sort angles of all lines in set B and do a match with pairs from set A. Example: If the angles are 0,5,50,93,129, then the lines with angles (0,5), (0,93), (5,93), (50, 129) are the matching candidates. Once you have the candidates you can further filter them.

Depending on the type of lines you have in set A, you can extract relevant features. Example: If all your lines are perpendicular or parallel, you can have features like distance between lines.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answer. I think I can see where you are coming from, though I get stuck from the outset with it. I am not sure how you get the set A can angle pairs? What does, for example, (0,0) represent in your example?<br/>Then it is a question of what I do next with it. Does this approach effectively give me possible matches between lines in the set and thus a heuristic, if you will, to reduce the search space at which I throw the Kabsch algorithm (or similar) to solve my translation and rotation?